# After installing Tensorflow 2.0 in a python 3.7.1 env, do I need to install Keras, or does Keras come bundled with TF2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I need to use Tensorflow 2.0(TF2.0) and Keras but I don't know if it's necessary to install both seperately or just TF2.0 (assuming TF2.0 has Keras bundled inside it). If I need to install TF2.0 only, will installing in a Python 3.7.1 be acceptable?

This is for Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems that it is bundled. You can check here https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2

Answer (score 2):

In Tensorflow 2.0 there is strong integration between TensorFlow and the Keras API specification (TF ships its own Keras implementation, that respects the Keras standard), therefore you don't have to install Keras separately since Keras already comes with TF in the `tf.keras` package.